# low remaining storage space, how do I increase it?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, storage, removable-storage

I keep getting low storage space warnings, I want to increase my total storage space, I was hoping to do that via terminal command, how would I go about doing that?

I put in `df -h` and got:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

udev            484M  4.0K  484M   1% /dev    
tmpfs           100M  1.3M   99M   2% /run    
/dev/sda1        18G   16G  564M  97% /    
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup    
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock    
none            498M  1.3M  496M   1% /run/shm    
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
```

I put in `mount` and got:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)    
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)    
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)    
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)    
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)    
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)    
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)    
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)    
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)    
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)    
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)    
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)    
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)   
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)    
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)    
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)    
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=dejel)
```

I Used `parted -l` And Got:

```
Model: ATA HTS541020G9SA00 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 20.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  18.9GB  18.9GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      18.9GB  20.0GB  1062MB  extended
 5      18.9GB  20.0GB  1062MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

I used `fdisk -l` and got:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 20.0 GB, 20003880960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2432 cylinders, total 39070080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a8ced
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    36993023    18495488   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        36995070    39069695     1037313    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        36995072    39069695     1037312   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Try posting the results of `df -h`, `mount`, and `fdisk -l`.  We have nothing to work on without those.

Comment: fdisk -l Yielded no output.

Comment: Looks like everything is in one partition.  Did you use the entire disk when you installed, or did you leave empty space?

Comment: i have no clue, don't know much about storage. just use of software programs.

Comment: OK.  Well, we need to know if there is any additional space available for you.  Your root partition is on 18GB, which makes sense if you're using a fifteen year old SCSI drive, but it's unusual for today.  How about `parted -l`?  Bear in mind, you need to be root for this (or the `fdisk` command above) to work - either use them as root or use `sudo`.

Comment: i am using a dell latitude D620, not sure if that helps, I'll run the commands you gave me though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do, other than replace the hard disk or get an external disk.

You can, of course, try to reduce the amount of disk space you're using, but most modern Linux distros will eat 20 gigs pretty quick.  That means you either trim out everything you don't need, or possibly change distributions to one that's a bit more trim (which will mean less functionality).  I don't know what your needs are, so I can't really recommend any more than that.  The only thing I work with personally that I'd label "trim" is OpenBSD, but I doubt you'll want to go that direction; there will be a steep learning curve.

You've got a 20GB disk in there.  I doubt it's original; the spec sheet from Dell lists the smallest drive offered at 40GB.  The good news is that it appears to be SATA - I'm not sure what the maximum size the BIOS supports on that machine, but as long as you don't go crazy it should be fine.  Pull it out first to make sure - if it has a bunch of little pins (around 44 or so of them), it's parallel ATA and will be harder to replace.  SATA will have two tabs with metal contacts on them.  A google search will show you the difference.

You should be able to pick up a larger drive used locally by asking around your more geeky friends.  Otherwise, a computer shop might have one in the hardware bin - it's worth checking out.  New ones can be had fairly cheap - but like I said, don't try to stuff a terabyte drive into that; I doubt it would work.  Make sure it's a laptop drive; desktops have physically larger drives that won't fit.

Search "dell latitude d620 hard drive" on youtube and you'll see videos on how to remove and replace the drive.

Comment: 20 gigs? My arch only takes no more than 5 after 2 year's use and regular clean up

Comment: try 'du  | sort -n'  to find space-eaters. Maybe you can clean out some of the stuff..

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough **RAM memory** (you can try `cat /sys/meminfo` to know how much yo have), then you can delete the **swap partition**, delete its references inside `/etc/fstab`, move `/dev/sda2` to the right and finally expand `/dev/sda1`.

You can also delete the whole content of `/usr/share/doc`

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea on a laptop. The swap zone is useful for hibernation

Comment: a) Where did he/she wrote, its a laptop? b) I don't think, that hibernation is a good idea with a 20GB hard drive. c) I don't think he/she has 506,5MB of ram memory, so its unlikely his/her swap partition works for hibernation....